# How to make a dynamic list from a multi variable table with boolean values?

Tags: excel, vba

Please help, very stumped with this one.

I've been provided with a matrix table as seen in image attached. I have a list of users, as well as the courses that they need to be enrolled in.

[image: Matrix Table - with courses]

I'm trying to create a list that will repeat the usernames for every course that they're enrolled in (in column A, and then a list of the courses they are enrolled in (column B)

[image: Table Output]

So far, I've been able to create such a list by creating a pivot table from this data, double clicking the grand total, and sorting the results, but this is a very manual process, and it needs to be replicated by others.

Is that possible?

Google Drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zXsWZCguia-SLaYAP-81kMX819879zzX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: this could be solved with [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: if you upload to onedrive/google drive a sample workbook and [edit] your question and post the link I could help you with the query

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I've uploaded and added to Google Drive. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @ChristopherSuk please learn [ask] and update your question with your efforts.

Comment: @teylyn one of my first times asking anything on here. Wasn't aware that I should mention everything I've done so far. 
Thanks for the great feedback

Comment: @teylyn he's asking for something to get started, I think if you point him to the right direction with a sample query is not encouraging lazyness.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz thank you for pointing in me in the right direction! I was able to figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome. Now  you know that to get help in this site, you have to show some effort and specifically post some code that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is just something to get you started:

Convert your data to an [Excel table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)

Steps:

**In Excel:**

1. Select the data range (starting from row 3)
2. Press `Ctrl` + `T`
3. Select Data | Get data from table

---

Transform your data in [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605)

**In Power Query:**

4. Select the columns headers (from FirstName to User)
5. Right click them
6. Select UnPivot other columns